# Adding child elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Plunkr is [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/muMAWO0UZ5O2ioxVZqSV)

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);  // so I can see the loop is executing.
  // attempt 1:
  let rb = $('<input type="radio" name="answer" value="' + i + '">' + i + '<br/>');
  //rb.appendTo('#target');

  // attempt 2:
  //$('#target').append('<input type="radio" name="answer" value="' + i + '">' + i + '<br/>');

  // attempt 3:
  $('#target').append(rb);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <h1>Derp</h1>
  <div id="target">

  </div>
</body>
```

Oddly enough I actually found this code ON StackOverflow, but for the life of me I don't understand why it's not working.  The plunkr shows 3 different methods I tried.

This is driving me nuts.  I am normally an Angular guy and have little need for jQuery.  But this SEEMS like it should work.

Help?

Comment: is it inside a `$(document).ready`?

Comment: All of these should work, assuming you're got your code running at the right time in the page lifecycle, and have included jQuery in the page.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a plunkr guy. Here's your code working on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ld3c9u17/.

Comment: Really, don't use external services for this code, it's simple enough for an inline snippet, which I've applied :)

Comment: Note that the snippet works because it automatically puts any jQuery code in a `$(function() { });` construct - that's likely the solution to OPs problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I agree entirely.

Comment: Yeah a buddy looked and pointed out that I needed to move script.js to the bottom.  I did that and it works.  Would have been nice if jQuery had mentioned that it was returning an empty selector list instead of just silently doing nothing.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh.  So apparently it's because my script is executing before the target div exists, as a friend pointed out.

I have been using async frameworks and loaders for so long I didn't even think about that.  Not sure I've encountered that particular problem since the 90s.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Out of pure curiosity, does it come into existence on `document.ready` or are you writing this `<div/>` into the page after the page loads?

Comment: the target div is in the markup the whole time.  It starts out there.

Answer (score 2):

If the `<div/>` is in the page from the start, your code is running before the DOM is ready, so wrap it in a [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler.

Here is one variant (additionally re-written to be a bit more functional):

```js
$(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('#target').append(
      $('<input type="radio" name="answer" value="' + i + '">' + i + '<br/>')
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <h1>Derp</h1>
  <div id="target"></div>
</body>
```

Or if you like ES6 and want to save concatenations:

```js
// ES6 Variant
$(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('#target').append(
      $(`<input type="radio" name="answer" value="${i}">${i}<br/>`)
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <h1>Derp</h1>
  <div id="target"></div>
</body>
```